# Pass class instances to other classes (or use global classes) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, design-patterns

i have some global classes, which means i use them on any other class.

Actual i do something like this:

```
class Log():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logs = []

    def log(self, msg):
        self.logs.append(msg)

class A():
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

class B():
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

class MyMain():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Log()
        self.a = A(self.logger)
        self.b = B(self.logger)
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to use classes like that on all submodules.. i searched a lot for a solution of this problem, but i am confused about the answers.
Is there a best practice on this..?

Thanks,
Toni.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but Python already has a fairly sophisticated logging package in it's stdlib, and from experience you're not going to come with anything better by yourself.

Comment: For a more general answer: do you expect each module to have it's own `Log` instance or do you want one single `Log` instance for the whole process or do you have more exact requirements ?

Comment: Logging was just an example. The class i'm creating will do much more..

Comment: Ok but this doesn't answer my second question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers.

Your answer relating to global var brought me to the following result. 
I will use it as an builtin class, due to it will be used inside multiple modules.

So that will work for me:

```
class Log():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logs = []

    def log(self, msg):
        self.logs.append(msg)

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        sc.log("test")

class MyMain():
    def __init__(self):
        builtins.sc = Log()
        self.a = A()
```

Thanks.